# 8051 Serial Port Receive Data Loss

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, 8051, data-loss

I am making simple messaging program such that I have two 8051 machine one of them is transmitter and the other is receiver. Transmitter sends 8 charachters which is coded as:

```
     ...
     mov r7, #8
     mov r0, #30h
TRS: clr TI
     mov sbuf, @r0
     inc r0
     jnb TI, $
     djnz r7, TRS
```

I get those 8 charachters from keyboard and they are surely on 30h to 37h. After getting those 8 chars I send the data. However the thing that i see in the receivers LCD is the first charachter of 8 byte. ie if i typed 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8, receiver can get only 1 and displays it. This is the code for receiver:

```
     ...
     mov r7, #8
REC: jnb RI, $
     mov a, sbuf
     acall SEND_DATA
     clr RI
     djnz r7, REC
```

Receiver waits for another 7 chars. When i type 64 chars from transmitter receiver takes only 8 of them which are mod8=1. I am clearing the RI flag and waiting for the next rising edge for RI which is supposed to be next char coming from trasmitter. What could be the reason?

Regards

Comment: Your receive code has no *flow control* and overloads the receiver function.  While the processor is executing SEND_DATA after *each/every* received character, more serial data can arrive but will not be serviced properly.  You can (or should always) check for receive *overrun* (and other errors such as framing error) to detect this condition.

Comment: You must wait until the transmitter is empty before writing the next character.  You are not using TI correctly.  You must not clr it, you must test it.